# How to choose the EPSG projection?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm, epsg

Up until now for reprojection of my WGS84 vector (.shp) and raster files (.tif), I have been using [EPSG projections](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/) based on vector/raster central point's UTM zone.

But what happens if the envelope-area of the vector or raster file spans through two UTM zones?
Here is an example of a raster spanning through UTM zones 40 and 41:

[image]

In that case is it even possible to use some EPSG projection or not?
Should one of the two UTM zones be picked?

Comment: Duplicate? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141496/which-utm-zone-to-use-for-a-large-country

Comment: You can always create your own projection system

Comment: Thank you for the replies.
-mkennedy: I took a look at the best answer by "Chris W", but I am not sure I understand it. Is it possible to somehow contact users?
-nmtoken: I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @marco what software are you using for reprojection?

Comment: Hi @neuhausr. I am using QGIS. Sorry for the later reply.

Answer (score 5):

before to create your own projection system, you might find one which fit your region of interest . But never "combine" different maps created in differents UTM zones into one map with the expectation of great precision.

from this [source](http://www.georeference.org/doc/universal_transverse_mercator_utm_.htm)

> If we need to combine objects from several different UTM zones, the
>   correct solution is to choose a different projection (such as a conic
>   or azimuthal projection) for the combined map that provides low
>   distortion over the entire region of interest

[...]

> UTM was designed to map objects within one zone at a time. It is a very bad choice if objects from several zones must be shown together on the same map.

Comment: Thank you for the useful reply Hugo! I didn't intend to combine data from different UTM zones, but this is still very useful information!