# Iterating intersect between polylines and polygons in QGIS using Python script?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a shapefile made up of 127 separate polygons that represent different districts.  Overlaid on this layer is a polyline layer of 2800 streets, some which are completely bound by the polygons and some which crisscross two or more polygons.

My task is two find the total length of streets within each polygon (district).  I've already done this with one district using Vector> Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect and then performing summary statsitics.  However, in order to avoid doing this manually 127 times, I would like to write a script that will iterate through each polygon - performing the intersect with the polyline layer and leaving me with 127 separate shapefiles.

I not very familiar with Python - I only know some very basic commands.  I've attached images to help you visualize and conceptualize the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create separate shapefiles for each district, first make sure your polygon layer contains unique attributes (if not, you can create one using the **Field Calculator** with the expression `$rownum`). You can then run the **Split Vector Layer** from *Vector > Data Management Tools > Split Vector Layer*. Choose a directory (for example: `C:/Users/you/Desktop/Test/Shapefiles//`) and each polygon district should have its own shapefile.

The following script should intersect each polygon district with the line layer:

```
import glob, os, processing

line_layer = "path/to/line_layer//"    # This is the path to your line layer
poly_layers = "C:/Users/you/Desktop/Test/Shapefiles//"  # This is the path to your district shapefiles
output_dir = "path/to/output_dir//"    # This is the path for the shapefiles to be saved

os.chdir(poly_layers)
for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
    processing.runalg("qgis:intersection", line_layer, fname, output_dir + fname)
```

Comment: I tried this -saved my shapefiles in a folder called "FINALDELIVERY" but I got the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/alexander/Desktop/Strelka/FINALDELIVERY'  Any ideas?

Comment: Strange, try adding double slashes at the end of the folder path.

Comment: That also didn't work.  I set the cwd to my Desktop, but for some reason when I ask the list the files in cwd, none of these files are actually on my Desktop.  os.listdir(cwd)
['.DocumentRevisions-V100', '.file', '.fseventsd', '.PKInstallSandboxManager', '.Spotlight-V100', '.Trashes', '.vol', 'Applications', 'bin', 'cores', 'dev', 'etc', 'home', 'installer.failurerequests', 'Library', 'net', 'Network', 'private', 'sbin', 'System', 'tmp', 'Users', 'usr', 'var', 'Volumes']

Comment: As soon as I try to change the working directory to any folder that is on my Desktop, I get the following error (however, I can change to cwd to Desktop, just none of the folders that are in Desktop) ------os.chdir("/Users/alexander/Documents/Strelka")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/alexander/Documents/Strelka'

Comment: I'm assuming you're using mac? Not quite sure what the problem is but the answer by @snaileater should also work.

Comment: I tried the recommendation by @snaileater but unfortunately, no matter how I re-reproject and re-save my layers, the sum line tool produces values that are very small.  I cannot seem to figure out how to get it the sum in meters.  I've tried using a UTM CRS, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an integrated tool in QGIS doing what you are expecting :
Go to **Vector/Analysis Tools/Sum Line Lengths** ...

Unless you want to do the task programmatically, of course ... But in that case you can call this tool from inside Python.

Comment: Thank you for the tip but that did not work - the output shapefile is the same as the input polygon vector layer however the added column does not correspond to the sum of the lengths of the streets within that polygon.

Comment: Huh ? working nicely on my side ... did u check the CRS of the layers ?

Comment: Yes, the CRS is the same for both layers - EPSG: 4326, WGS84.  The length column that is added to the output shapefile has all values that are between 0 and 1, which is impossible because the lengths should be in thousands of meters.

Comment: I think u won't get meters if your layers are in WGS84 ...

Comment: What should I do to get meters?

Comment: I think the following link should help u :    
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43198/how-to-get-length-in-meters-in-qgis

Comment: Please do not abbreviate "you" as "u" in any questions or answers that you post here.